# SSIS stops with no errors after script task

Tags: ssis, task

A strange thing is happening in SSIS 2008. I have a script component where I set a value for a user variable. The script does what it has to do and then SSIS stops running. All components turn green, so there is no error. The next component that needs to run is the execute process task where I use a CMD command to copy files (XCOPY). If I run the CMD command directly under a command prompt, it works.

Do I neeed to set some properties of the script component in order that it can go through the next component?

No there is no constraint.

Comment: Is there a precedence constraint linking the tasks?

Comment: No there is no precedence constraint

Comment: Could you post screen shots of the control and data flows in question, along with the source code for the script? As this question stands, there's not nearly enough information available for anyone to help.